# How do I pass variables from a post function in jquery to the claim controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have 2 variables that I would like to add to a post function.  How do I do this?

```
    $.post('/Home/AddContent/',  function (response) {
        alert("success");
    }, 'json');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery.post( 
    url, 
    [ data ], 
    [ success(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) ], 
    [ dataType ] 
)
```

this is the usage of jquery [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). take the "data" option

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.post(
    '/Home/AddContent/', //URL
    'variable1=' + uriEncodeComponent(value1),  //Data
    function(jsonObject, t, j)){ //Success
        alert('success');
    }, 
    'json' //Datatype
);
```